# How to get last inserted ID with GO-MSSQLDB driver?

Tags: sql, sql-server, go

I gathered that `SQL Server` does not return last inserted id automatically and I need to do it manually with: `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` within `SQL insert` statement.

How do I pick it up later in `Go code`?

The function in question is:

```
    func (sta *state) mkLogEntry(from time.Time, to time.Time, man bool) (id int64) {
    qry := "INSERT INTO ROMEExportLog(FromDate,ToDate,ExecutedAt,ExecutedManually,ExportWasSuccessful,UpdatedDaysIrregular) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID " +
        "VALUES(@FromDate,@ToDate,@ExecutedAt,@ExecutedManually,@ExportWasSuccessful,@UpdatedDaysIrregular)"
    res, err := sta.db.Exec(qry,
        sql.Named("FromDate", from),
        sql.Named("ToDate", to),
        sql.Named("ExecutedAt", time.Now()),
        sql.Named("ExecutedManually", man),
        sql.Named("ExportWasSuccessful", false),
        sql.Named("UpdatedDaysIrregular", false),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    id, err = res.LastInsertId()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return
}
```

The `res.LastInsertId()` returns `There is no generated identity value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is because PostgreSQL does not return you the last inserted id. This is because last inserted id is available only if you create a new row in a table that uses a sequence.

If you actually insert a row in the table where a sequence is assigned, you have to use RETURNING clause. Something like this: `INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES("val") RETURNING id`.

I am not sure about your driver, but in [pq](https://github.com/lib/pq) you will do this in the following way:

```
lastInsertId := 0
err = db.QueryRow("INSERT INTO brands (name) VALUES($1) RETURNING id", name).Scan(&lastInsertId)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I figured it out as well.. All I had to do was to Query instead of Exec and Scan the value as if it was a select statement.

Comment: Why does this answer refer to PostgreSQL when the question is tagged Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I think go-mssqldb driver defines PostgreSQL

Comment: No, that's the driver for Microsoft SQL Server, as is the tag on the question, as is the name "SQL Server" as a product, as is the keyword `OUTPUT` which is similar to `RETURNING` for PostgreSQL.

Comment: This answer is not related to the SQL server, and it's not working at all

Answer (score 3):

FOR SQL SERVER:

This may be gimmicky... But I found that using `QueryRow`
will run **multiple** queries/commands and just return the **LAST** row.

```
if err := db.QueryRow(`
    INSERT INTO [TABLE] ([COLUMN]) VALUES (?); 
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, 
    colValue
).Scan(&id); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

As long as `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is the last row returned then this essentially does what I would have expected result.LastInsertId() to do.